# Image compression like Whatsapp and other messengers on Android

Tags: android, compression

I am using the following code for image compression.

The code compresses image files that are larger than 2 MB.

But this code takes time and image quality stays pure.

```
public static String compressImage(String imagePath, Context context)
    {
        String resizeImagePath = null;
        String filePath = imagePath;
        CustomLogHandler.printDebug(TAG, "resizeImagePath:" + imagePath);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;
        int imageScal = 1;

        // File size greater then 2mb
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        File imgFile = new File(filePath);
        double bytes = imgFile.length();
        double kilobytes = (bytes / 1024);
        double megabytes = (kilobytes / 1024);

        AppConfig.makeLog(TAG, "image size in mb:" + df.format(megabytes), 0);

        double filesize = Double.parseDouble(df.format(megabytes));
        if (filesize > 2.00f)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < filesize; i = i + 2)
            {

                imageScal++;
            }
            int remind = imageScal / 2;
            if (remind != 0)
            {
                imageScal = imageScal + 1;
            }

            makeLog(TAG, "image scale:" + imageScal, 0);

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

            int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
            int actualWidth = options.outWidth;
            float maxHeight = 4000;
            float maxWidth = 6000;
            // float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;
            // float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

            if (actualHeight > maxHeight)
            {
                imageScal = imageScal + 4;
            }

            if (actualWidth > maxWidth)
            {
                imageScal = imageScal + 8;
            }

            // if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth)
            // {
            // if (imgRatio < maxRatio)
            // {
            // imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
            // actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
            // actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
            //
            // }
            // else if (imgRatio > maxRatio)
            // {
            // imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
            // actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
            // actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
            // }
            // else
            // {
            // actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
            // actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
            //
            // }
            // }

            // options.inSampleSize = utils.calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);
            options.inSampleSize = imageScal;
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            options.inDither = true;
            options.inPurgeable = true;
            options.inInputShareable = true;
            options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

            try
            {
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
                bmp = decodeFile(filePath);
            }
            catch (OutOfMemoryError exception)
            {
                exception.printStackTrace();

            }
            boolean done = false;

            while (!done)
            {
                try
                {
                    scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

                    // scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

                    done = true;
                }
                catch (OutOfMemoryError exception)
                {
                    // 15923 × 1790
                    // 5616 × 3744
                    // 8150 × 9154
                    actualWidth = actualWidth - ((actualWidth * 2) / 100);
                    actualHeight = actualHeight - ((actualHeight * 2) / 100);
                    // scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(5616, 3744, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
            float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
            float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
            float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

            Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
            scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
            canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

            // Resize image stored in sdcard
            FileOutputStream out = null;
            // filename =AppConfig.fileTosaveMedia(context, FileType.IMAGE, true).getAbsolutePath();
            int compress = 50;
            try
            {
                do
                {
                    imgFile = AppConfig.fileTosaveMedia(context, FileType.IMAGE, true);
                    out = new FileOutputStream(imgFile);
                    scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, compress, out);

                    resizeImagePath = imgFile.getAbsolutePath();

                    // Thread.sleep(15000);
                    // imgFile = new File(filename);
                    bytes = imgFile.length();
                    kilobytes = (bytes / 1024);
                    megabytes = (kilobytes / 1024);
                    System.out.println("resized image size in mb:" + df.format(megabytes));

                    filesize = Double.parseDouble(df.format(megabytes));
                    if (filesize > 2.00f)
                    {
                        compress = 30;
                    }
                } while (filesize > 2.00f);
                scaledBitmap.recycle();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {

            FileOutputStream out = null;
            // FileInputStream in = null;
            imgFile = AppConfig.fileTosaveMedia(context, FileType.IMAGE, true);
            resizeImagePath = imgFile.getAbsolutePath();
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream outTemp = null;
            try
            {

                // create output directory if it doesn't exist

                in = new FileInputStream(filePath);
                outTemp = new FileOutputStream(resizeImagePath);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int read;
                while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
                {
                    outTemp.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                in.close();
                in = null;

                // write the output file (You have now copied the file)
                outTemp.flush();
                outTemp.close();
                outTemp = null;

            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe1)
            {
                Log.e("tag", fnfe1.getMessage());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
            }

            // try
            // {
            // Bitmap bmp = decodeFile(filePath);
            // // in = new FileInputStream(new File(imagePath));
            // // persistImage(bitmap, name);
            // out = new FileOutputStream(resizeImagePath);
            // bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            // out.flush();
            // out.close();
            // // FileIO.copyStream(in, out);
            // }
            // catch (Exception e)
            // {
            // e.printStackTrace();
            // }
        }
        CustomLogHandler.printDebug(TAG, "resizeImagePath:" + resizeImagePath);
        return resizeImagePath;
    }
```

I spent so much time on Google search and reading blogs. Then after creating the above code, I found [this](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-technique-algorithm-used-by-messengers-like-WhatsApp-and-BBM-to-compress-images).

Is the above code correct? Or is there any other library to use to compress images?

Please help me.

Answer (score 25):

Try below code :-

```
public String compressImage(String imageUri) {

        String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

//      by setting this field as true, the actual bitmap pixels are not loaded in the memory. Just the bounds are loaded. If
//      you try the use the bitmap here, you will get null.
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
        int actualWidth = options.outWidth;

//      max Height and width values of the compressed image is taken as 816x612

        float maxHeight = 816.0f;
        float maxWidth = 612.0f;
        float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;
        float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

//      width and height values are set maintaining the aspect ratio of the image

        if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
            if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {               imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;                actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);               actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;             } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
                actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
            } else {
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

            }
        }

//      setting inSampleSize value allows to load a scaled down version of the original image

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);

//      inJustDecodeBounds set to false to load the actual bitmap
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

//      this options allow android to claim the bitmap memory if it runs low on memory
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        options.inInputShareable = true;
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

        try {
//          load the bitmap from its path
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();

        }
        try {
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
        float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
        float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
        float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

        Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
        scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

//      check the rotation of the image and display it properly
        ExifInterface exif;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if (orientation == 6) {
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 3) {
                matrix.postRotate(180);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 8) {
                matrix.postRotate(270);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            }
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                    scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                    true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FileOutputStream out = null;
        String filename = getFilename();
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(filename);

//          write the compressed bitmap at the destination specified by filename.
            scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return filename;

    }
```

for for information see below link :-

http://voidcanvas.com/whatsapp-like-image-compression-in-android/

Comment: Hi voidcanvas, I did use you code but it did not work incase where I used a camera to take photos, it only worked for the galllery part. the error is not clear as it says: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() and  at com.ambalika.efficientimageloading.BitmapActivity$ImageCompressionAsyncTask.getRealPathFromURI(BitmapActivity.java:313)...

Comment: @ombiro not getting you properly

Comment: Hi , I am using your code currently but am facing a slight issue. The max width and height given is in pixels so when I click a picture from a high res phone and transfer it to a low res one after compression, the picture gets very distorted.

Comment: I have tested the code from voidcanvas, an it really amazing. It good. I used it to compress a picture of 3.82MB to 47.26KB. @user3748230, I will advice you to check out the complete code from the link given above

Comment: @Senator. Iv run the same code but could only get a 2.8MB down to about 137KB. What were your maxWidth/maxLength values?

Comment: @VernonCliveKawonza, I don't remember the image dimension but it worked well. We were able to optmise the code and create a library from it. You check it with this [github link](https://github.com/Tourenathan-G5organisation)

Comment: @Senator , I stumbled upon this library last night, and looking at the demos, i noticed that you cant specify the location where you want the image to be saved. Did i miss something?

Comment: @VernonCliveKawonza, Sure you didn't miss anything. Try to use it and leave us some feedback

Comment: @Senator, but i would really like to control where the image is saved to

Comment: This code is working fine 2.70 MB picture converted into 136KB, but quality is not too much good like whatsapp. what i need to do if picture size is 2.70MB after compression i will get 500kb image.

Comment: Can you please tell me why i am getting error at `exif = new ExifInterface(filePath)` with `A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called` I am using strict mode policy

Answer (score 2):

Hope Helps this

```
  public static String compressImage(String filePath) {


    Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();



    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

    int actualHeight = options.outHeight;

    int actualWidth = options.outWidth;


    float maxHeight = 400.0f;
    float maxWidth = 300.0f;

    float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;

    float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;



    if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) 
    {

        if (imgRatio < maxRatio) { 

         imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;

            actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);   

        actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;    

    } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {

            imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;

            actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);

            actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

        } else {

            actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;

            actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

        }
    }



    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth,   
                             actualHeight);


   //      inJustDecodeBounds set to false to load the actual bitmap

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;


     //      this options allow android to claim the bitmap memory if it runs low on memory
    options.inPurgeable = true;

    options.inInputShareable = true;

    options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];


    try {

    //          load the bitmap from its path

        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

    } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {

        exception.printStackTrace();

    }
    try {

        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, 
                           actualHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {

        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;

    float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;

    float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;

    float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;


    Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();

    scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);



    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);

    canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);

    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));


    //      check the rotation of the image and display it properly

    ExifInterface exif;

    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);

        Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

        if (orientation == 6) {

            matrix.postRotate(90);

            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);

        } else if (orientation == 3) {

            matrix.postRotate(180);

            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);

        } else if (orientation == 8) {

            matrix.postRotate(270);

            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);

        }
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                true);

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FileOutputStream out = null;

    String filename = getFilename();

    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(filename);


        //          write the compressed bitmap at the destination specified by filename.
        scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return filename;

}

public static String getFilename() {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "Foldername/Images");

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }
    String uriSting = (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

    return uriSting;

}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    final int height = options.outHeight;

    final int width = options.outWidth;

    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height/ (float) 
reqHeight);

        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio; 

 }       final float totalPixels = width * height; 

 final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;  

 while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
        inSampleSize++;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap highlightImage(Bitmap src) {

      // create new bitmap, which will be painted and becomes result image

      Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth() + 96, src.getHeight() + 96, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

      // setup canvas for painting

      Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOut);

      // setup default color

      canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

      // create a blur paint for capturing alpha

      Paint ptBlur = new Paint();

      ptBlur.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(15, Blur.NORMAL));

      int[] offsetXY = new int[2];

      // capture alpha into a bitmap

      Bitmap bmAlpha = src.extractAlpha(ptBlur, offsetXY);

      // create a color paint
      Paint ptAlphaColor = new Paint();

      ptAlphaColor.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);

      // paint color for captured alpha region (bitmap)

      canvas.drawBitmap(bmAlpha, offsetXY[0], offsetXY[1], ptAlphaColor);

      // free memory

      bmAlpha.recycle();

      // paint the image source
      canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);

      // return out final image
      return bmOut;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
private void previewCapturedImage() {
    try {

        int targetW = 450;
        int targetH = 450;
        Log.e("Get w", "width" + targetW);
        Log.e("Get H", "height" + targetH);
        // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, bmOptions);
        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

        // Determine how much to scale down the image
        int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH);

        // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor << 1;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, bmOptions);

        Matrix mtx = new Matrix();

        try {

            File imageFile = new File(filename);
            imageFile1 = imageFile;
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(
                    imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
            Log.e("Orintation", "  :-" + orientation);
            switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:

                mtx.postRotate(270);
                rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                        bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), mtx, true);
                if (rotatedBMP != bitmap)
                    bitmap.recycle();
                imgPreview.setImageBitmap(rotatedBMP);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:

                mtx.postRotate(180);
                rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                        bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), mtx, true);
                if (rotatedBMP != bitmap)
                    bitmap.recycle();
                imgPreview.setImageBitmap(rotatedBMP);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:

                mtx.postRotate(90);
                rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                        bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), mtx, true);
                if (rotatedBMP != bitmap)
                    bitmap.recycle();
                imgPreview.setImageBitmap(rotatedBMP);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:

                mtx.postRotate(0);
                rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                        bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), mtx, true);
                if (rotatedBMP != bitmap)
                    bitmap.recycle();
                imgPreview.setImageBitmap(rotatedBMP);
                break;
            default:
                mtx.postRotate(0);
                rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                        bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), mtx, true);
                if (rotatedBMP != bitmap)
                    bitmap.recycle();
                imgPreview.setImageBitmap(rotatedBMP);
                // img_profilepic.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                // .decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath));

            }
            double megabytes = 0;
            if (imageFile1.exists()) {

                double bytes = imageFile1.length();
                double kilobytes = (bytes / 1024);
                megabytes = (kilobytes / 1024);
                double gigabytes = (megabytes / 1024);
                double terabytes = (gigabytes / 1024);
                double petabytes = (terabytes / 1024);
                double exabytes = (petabytes / 1024);
                double zettabytes = (exabytes / 1024);
                double yottabytes = (zettabytes / 1024);
                Log.e("Image Size After in KB", "20th May:" + kilobytes);
                Log.e("Image Size After in MB", "20th May:" + megabytes);

            }
            int AfterSize = rotatedBMP.getRowBytes()
                    * rotatedBMP.getHeight();
            Log.e("After Compress Withd ",
                    "21st May ::" + rotatedBMP.getWidth());
            Log.e("After Compress Withd ",
                    "21st May ::" + rotatedBMP.getWidth());
            Log.i("RotateImage", "Exif orientation: " + orientation);
            tv_After.setText("After Width:" + rotatedBMP.getWidth()
                    + " :Height:" + rotatedBMP.getHeight() + ":in MB :"
                    + megabytes + " :Bitmap: " + AfterSize);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

also put this method.

```
public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }
    final float totalPixels = width * height;
    final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;
    while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap)     {
        inSampleSize++;
    }
    Log.e("In Sample Size..", "19th May :-" + inSampleSize);
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Top answer...
The mentioned method is not working, it returning empty path in some Xiaomi phones because there is some problem with getting file path from Uri.
use the **getFilePath()** instead of **getRealPathFromURI()**... and change parameters from **compressImage(String imageUri)** to **compressImage(Uri imageUri)**.

```
private static String getFilePath(Context context, Uri uri) {
    String selection = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    // Uri is different in versions after KITKAT (Android 4.4), we need to
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context.getApplicationContext(), uri)) {
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
        } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
        } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }
            selection = "_id=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{
                    split[1]
            };
        }
    }
    if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
        };
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver()
                    .query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }
    return null;
}

private static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

private static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

private static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about WhatsApp but, I manage to understand how Telegram does it by reading from the source code, and I make an article on my blog about how they do it step by step, which you can find here [rifqimfahmi.dev/blog/telegram-like-image-optimization-on-android](https://rifqimfahmi.dev/blog/telegram-like-image-optimization-on-android/).